# TSQL Field Order Increment during Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple query that is taking in an XML string and inserting one or more rows of data depending on what was selected on the UI.

There is a field on the records that determine their order and by default, these new fields are added to the end of the table.

If 3 records exist with the `OrderID` of `1,2,3` respectively and I add 3 more records through the XML string, those records should get `4,5,6` as their `orderID`. It doesn't matter which 3 values in the new set get which order, just that they continue the incrementation.

Here was my attempt, which works fine if there is a single item but if there are multiple, `@newOrder` is always the same so the count is invalid with `@newOrder+1`.

```
-- Get the next order based on the last entry
DECLARE @newOrder INT = (SELECT TOP 1 DepartmentOrder FROM c.department WHERE dID = @dID ORDER BY DepartmentOrder DESC)


-- Add new department
    INSERT INTO c.department (dID,DepartmentID,DepartmentOrder)

    SELECT @dID,
           ParamValues.x1.value('departmentID[1]', 'int'),
           ISNULL(@newOrder,0)+1
    FROM @departments.nodes('/departments/department') AS ParamValues(x1)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not use an identity column? ("risk" of gaps aside)

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include the relevant table DDL and sample xml so that we could recreate the issue.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The orders can overlap based on the `dID`. For example `dID=1` could have 3 records with 1,2,3 as the orderID. `dID=2` could have 4 records, 1,2,3,4 as their orderIDs. When i query based on the dID, i get the records and sort them by their order that was defined.

Comment: I would suggest having an identity column to store the absolute order of the rows insertion. 

Use `row_number` when selecting from the table to get the `orderId` - unless the `orderId` needs to be persistent even if you delete records (meaning, if you have orders 1, 2, 3 and deleted order #2 you need the numbers 1, 3 and not 1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the new values:

```
INSERT INTO c.department (dID,DepartmentID,DepartmentOrder)
SELECT @dID,
       ParamValues.x1.value('departmentID[1]', 'int'),
       ISNULL(@newOrder,0)+ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ParamValues.x1)
FROM @departments.nodes('/departments/department') AS ParamValues(x1)
```

By using the XML column `x1` in the `ORDER BY` clause, you are specifying that the DepartmentOrder should be ordered the same way the nodes appear in the xml.